# @NotNull not working on embedded classes, using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following two `Address`, `User` classes:

```java
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String street;
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @Valid
    private Address homeAddress;
}
```

And this is generating the following MySQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `street` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

As you can see, the `@NotNull` constraint worked for the `username` field, and the `@Size(max = 50)` constraint worked for the embedded class. However, the `@NotNull` constraint on the embedded class doesn't seem to working, what am I missing?

The `pom.xml`, in case it's relevant:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.manning.javapersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapping-value-types</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mapping-value-types</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Hibernate overrides your setting of `@NotNull` on `Address.street` when generating the table for the `User` entity is that the field `User.homeAddress` itself is nullable. **This means that you have specified that it is perfectly fine to pass a `User` object with `null` `homeAddress` to Hibernate.** And Hibernate (JPA generally I think) will deal with it by making all the fields of the embeddable *nullable*.

Maybe you can try annotating the `User.homeAddress` field as `@NotNull` -or- orverride the embedded column definition with `@Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name="street", column=@Column(..., nullable=false))})`.

Comment: Setting `User.homeAddress` as `@NotNull` did solve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the recently published book: [Java Persistence with Spring Data and Hibernate](https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-spring-data-and-hibernate), the authors mention the following:

> Problem: Hibernate Validator doesn’t generate NOT NULL constraints
> At the time of writing, an open flaw remains with Hibernate Validator: Hibernate won’t map @NotNull constraints on embeddable component properties to NOT NULL constraints when generating the database schema. Hibernate will only use @NotNull on the components’ properties at runtime for Bean Validation. We have to map the property with @Column(nullable = false) to generate the constraint in the schema. The Hibernate bug database is tracking this problem as HVAL-3 (see http://mng.bz/lR0R).

Comment: Yes, that was were my question came from. But as you can see in the accepted answer, the authors are horribly wrong.